# Using custom preprocessor with jupyter nbconvert v5.3.1 on the command line

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I'm trying to execute a custom preprocessor I wrote called `RemoveCellsWithNoTags` on the command line. Following the [documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.1/config_options.html), this is my attempted command

```
jupyter nbconvert --Exporter.preprocessors=["custompreprocessor.RemoveCellsWithNoTags"] --to script mynotebook.ipynb
```

This gives me the following error

```
zsh: no matches found: --Exporter.preprocessors=[custompreprocessor.RemoveCellsWithNoTags]
```

The standard command works fine

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script mynotebook.ipynb
```

For completeness here is the code in my `custompreprocessor.py` file.

```
from nbconvert.preprocessors import Preprocessor

class RemoveCellsWithNoTags(Preprocessor):

    def preprocess(self, notebook, resources):
        notebook.cells = [cell for cell in notebook.cells if 'tags' in cell.metadata]
        return notebook, resources
```

#### Update #1 - Workaround using a config file

I have managed to get this working with a configuration file, while this is not ideal for me, it is working.

`nb_convert_config.py` file contents

```
c = get_config()

c.NbConvertApp.notebooks = ['mynotebook.ipynb']
c.NbConvertApp.export_format = 'python'
c.Exporter.preprocessors = ['custompreprocessor.RemoveCellsWithNoTags']
```

The command then becomes

```
jupyter nbconvert --config nbconvert_config.py
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably just need to escape the `[` and `]` from your shell (**zsh** it seems):

```
jupyter nbconvert \
  --Exporter.preprocessors=\["custompreprocessor.RemoveCellsWithNoTags"\] \
  --to script mynotebook.ipynb
```

The clue is in the error message you get

```
zsh: no matches found: --Exporter.preprocessors=[custompreprocessor.RemoveCellsWithNoTags]
```

The error message is from the shell - *not* `jupyter-nbconvert`.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax is as follows:

`preprocess.py`

```py
from nbconvert.preprocessors import Preprocessor

class RemoveCellsWithNoTags(Preprocessor):
    def preprocess(self, notebook, resources):
        executable_cells = []
        for cell in notebook.cells:
            if cell.metadata.get('tags'):
                if "skip" in cell.metadata.get('tags'):
                    continue
            executable_cells.append(cell)
        notebook.cells = executable_cells
        return notebook, resources
```

Then export notebook:

```
jupyter nbconvert --Exporter.preprocessors=[\"preprocess.RemoveCellsWithNoTags\"] getting-started-keras.ipynb
```